# Gravatar does not work with anonymous accounts

Tags: 8, media

I enabled the avatars_gravatar submodule from [Avatar Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/avatars) and configured it to be the only available Avatar Generator in `admin/config/people/avatars`. The Gravatar is rendered for logged in users, but not for anonymous users that leave a comment.

Is this a configuration issue or do I need to alter a template? I'm using the standard Bartik theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately anonymous accounts arn't supported at this time, because they are a special case. Avatar Kit is currently written to work with Drupal user entities, which anonymous accounts are not.

Follow https://github.com/dpi/avatars/issues/30 for progress